CCAvenue settings button is missing in WordPress
I am using WordPress 6.5.5 for a website. I installed the CCAvenue plugin in WordPress, but after installation, the 'CCAvenue Payment Gateway for WooCommerce' appeared in
Plugins -> Installed Plugins 

without the Settings button. I only have a Deactivate button. Why didn't the Settings button appear?


Perhaps the plugin simply doesn't show a Settings link in that location ...? The documentation says you should go to WC settings page, and the Payment Gateways tab, to configure the plugin ...
